# Game Object does not retain its original position when left in space on drag n drop in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

There is a game Object "Heat" in Unity 2D. I am trying to drag and drop game object on another game object Sun using UI(works for unity version greater than 4.6). Drag works right but when I drop the object in space other than Sun, heat object does not retain its original position. I tried to make it work using colliders and raycasting but it does not seem to work. Here is the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Drag : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

    public static GameObject itemBeingDragged;
    public static Vector2 startPos;


    void Start () {

    }



    #region IBeginDragHandler implementation
    public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        itemBeingDragged = gameObject;
        startPos = transform.position;

    }
    #endregion


    #region IDragHandler implementation
    public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = eventData.position;

    }
    #endregion

    #region IEndDragHandler implementation

    public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
    {

        //if itemBeingDragged is in Space then move it to its original position and then assign null 

        //itemBeingDragged = null;



        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast (Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);

        if (hit.collider != null) 
        {   

            print ("Inside hit.collider" + hit.collider.name);


            //Itembeing Dragged  ... set it to startPos if released in space

            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Heat")
            {

                LeanTween.move (hit.collider.gameObject,PublicVariables.startPosHeat, 1.5f);


            }

        }
    }


    #endregion


}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, it doesn't "retain its original position"? Isn't changing the position the whole point of drag-drop functionality?

Comment: In case game object is dragged and then dropped to space, it is suppose to go back to its previous position.